# Exponential map for the Lie group of upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be the Lie group of all upper triangular real matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$) with *positive diagonal elements*. Denote $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra.

1. Do we have surjectivity of $\exp : \mathfrak{g}\to G$ ? and what about injectivity?
2. Is $\mathfrak{g}$ equal to the algebra of all upper triangular matrices?

Answer (score 2):

The exponential map $\exp\colon \mathfrak{n}^+\rightarrow N$ from the nilpotent Lie algebra of all *stricly* upper-triangular matrices to the nilpotent group of all upper uni-triangular matrices is given by polynomial maps with inverse given by matrix logarithm. Hence $\exp$ is bijective in this case. This is no longer true for upper-triangular matrices. The question when $\exp$ is injective is easier than the question when $\exp$ is surjective. For injectivity we have very nice criteria, given for example at [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective/1592257#1592257):

If $G$ is a real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $\exp$ is injective
2. $\exp$ is bijective
3. $\exp$ is a real analytic diffeomorphism
4. $G$ is solvable, simply connected, and $\mathfrak{g}$ does not admit $\mathfrak{e}$ as subalgebra of a quotient.
5. $G$ is solvable, simply connected, and $\mathfrak{g}$ does not admit $\mathfrak{e}$ or $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$ as subalgebra

Here $\mathfrak{e}$ is the 3-dimensional Lie algebra with basis $(H,X,Y)$ and bracket $[H,X]=Y$, $[H,Y]=-X$, $[X,Y]=0$. It is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of the group of isometries of the plane. Its central extension $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$ is defined as the 4-dimensional Lie algebra defined by adding a central generator $Z$ and the additional nonzero bracket $[X,Y]=Z$.

Concerning  surjectivity the situation is more complicated, see 
[On surjectivity of exponential map for Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups?rq=1),  or [Exponential map is surjective for compact connected Lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089636/exponential-map-is-surjective-for-compact-connected-lie-group?rq=1).

So, for 1. Yes, $\exp$ is surjective, because every upper-triangular real matrix with positive diagonal entries is invertible and is the square of an invertible matrix, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191228/image-of-matrix-exponential-map).

For 2.) Yes.