# Showing surjectivity of exponential map.

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

**TL;DR:** How to show eq. (2) using eq. (1)?

---

I'm currently having a bit of a hard time with the following problem. In class we showed that 
$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3;\mathbb{C})\cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}),\tag{1}$$
where $\mathfrak{so}(1,3;\mathbb{C})$ is the Lie algebra of the proper Lorentz group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ the Lie algebra of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. If I understood my tutor correctly it is possible to show that 
$$SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C}),\tag{2}$$
using eq. (1). For this to be true we would need to show that $\exp$ is surjective on the Lie algebras separately, aka
$$\exp: \mathfrak{g}_i\to G_i,$$
where $\mathfrak{g}_1=\mathfrak{so}(1,3;\mathbb{C}),G_1 = SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$,$G_2 =SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

---

The problem with this is that I don't really know how to do that... I thought that I'd try first to show that $\exp:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})\to SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is surjective and then try to work out the rest from there. Unfortunately it turned out that $\exp$ isn't surjective on this Lie algebra.. Could somebody suggest some strategies to prove this?

Comment: The exponential function is **not** surjective in this case, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry, but I'm not incredibly familiar with topology (physics student here) so I'm having a hard time following the statements there... But since the question is flawed in itself, according to Thomas it should be $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\{\pm 1\}\cong SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})$, I would like to know if the exponential map is not sujective in this case either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result $SO(3,1, C)=Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C)$ is certainly not true. The lfh is isomoprhic to $SO(4,C)$, whose center is $Z/2Z$. The right hand side has center $Z/2Z \times Z/2Z.$ Let $Z\subset Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C)$ the subgroup with two element $(Id,Id) ; -(Id,Id)$.

If you want to prove that $Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C) /Z$, is $SO(4,C)$ firts identify $C^4$ with the set of $(2,2)$ matrices with quadratic from the determinant $(ad-bc)$ (this is a quadratic form !).

Note that this quadratic form is $Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C) /Z$ invariant where the action is $(g,h).M=gMh^{-1}$, with kernel $Z$.

So we have a morphism $Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C)/Z\to SO(4,C)$.

It is quite easy to prove injectivity : if for every $M$,$M=gMh^{-1}$ then we have $g=h$ (let $M=id$), and then $g$ commute with every matrix so must be central of determinant 1.

For the surjectivity this follows from dimension plus injectivity of the analytic morphism we just have described.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer! Forget the comment before, I just understood what your notation is and how I'm supposed to read it... I will try to follow it and come back later if a question arises!

Comment: After some trying out I just can't figure out some of your steps... For example, you wirte "Note that this quadratic form is $Sl(2,C)\times Sl(2,C)/Z$ invariant where the action is $(g,h).M=gMh^{−1}$, with kernel $Z$." Why should this be invariant? Could you help here a bit...

Comment: The quadratic form is the determinant. $det(gMh^{-1}=det(M)$, as both $g,h$ are with determinant 1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I‘m almost there... My last question is about your proof of injectivity. Can you expand that part a bit... I just can‘t figure out what steps you are doing and why.

Comment: $gM=Mh$ for evry $M$ implies $g=h$ ($M=id)$ Then $gMg^{_1}=M$ for every $M$ implies that $g$ is an homothety.