# A connected Lie group for which the exp map is not surjective

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, connectedness

I know that if a Lie group $G$ is not compact so the map $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$  is not necessarily surjective. But I am not absolutely sure if $\exp$ must be surjective if $G$ is connected.

I'm looking for an answer, maybe an example of connected Lie group for which the $\exp$ map wouldn't be surjective.

Many thanks, in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. Certainly the exponential map *can* be surjective when $G$ is non-compact.

Comment: The simplest example of a noncompact group where exp isn't surjective is SL(2,R), and that's connected.

Comment: Voted as duplicate of [On surjectivity of exponential map for Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301504/on-surjectivity-of-exponential-map-for-lie-groups): this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/301587/35400) gives a connected example ($\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$) for failure of surjectivity.